# Count unique instances in a column given the names of two other columns

Tags: r, count, unique, apply

I've got the following table (which is called train) (in reality much bigger)

```
UNSPSC adaptor alert bact blood collection packet patient ultrasoft whit
 514415       1     0    1     0          0      0       0         1    0
 514415       0     0    0     1          1      0       0         1    0
 514415       0     0    1     0          0      0       0         1    0
 514415       0     0    0     0          0      0       0         1    0
 514415       1     0    1     0          0      0       0         1    0
 514415       0     0    0     0          0      0       0         1    0
 422018       1     0    1     0          0      0       0         1    0
 422018       0     0    0     0          0      0       0         1    0
 422018       0     0    0     1          0      0       0         1    0
 411011       0     0    0     0          0      0       0         1    0
```

and the following table which I'll call associations:

```
 lhd     rhs
blood   collection
adaptor bact
[...]
```

I want to calculate the number of unique UNSPSC per column where the value is equal to 1 per each record in the association table for both lhs and rhs. 
Like:

blood    collection 1
adaptor  bact       2

This code does it for just one term at the time.

```
apply(train[,-1], 2, function(x) length(unique(substr(train$UNSPSC,1,4)[x == 1])))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of iterating over `trains` you can iterate over `associations` and use `subset` (subsets where `x` row column 1 and 2 are equal to `1`), `unique`, `length` functions.
Columns from row `x` are called using `get` function.

```
train$lhd <- 1
train$rhs <- 1
apply(associations, 1, function(x)
    length(unique(subset(train, get(x[1]) == 1 & get(x[2]) == 1)$UNSPSC))
)
# [1] 3 1 2
```

---

Data (`train`):

```
structure(list(UNSPSC = c(514415L, 514415L, 514415L, 514415L, 
514415L, 514415L, 422018L, 422018L, 422018L, 411011L), adaptor = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), alert = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), bact = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), blood = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L
), collection = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), packet = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), patient = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ultrasoft = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), whit = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), lhd = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), rhs = c(1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("UNSPSC", "adaptor", "alert", 
"bact", "blood", "collection", "packet", "patient", "ultrasoft", 
"whit", "lhd", "rhs"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Data (`associations`):

```
structure(list(V1 = c("lhd", "blood", "adaptor"), V2 = c("rhs", 
"collection", "bact")), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

A similar option with `tidyverse` would be (data from @PoGibas post) to apply `pmap` on the 'associations' data to loop over the columns, `filter` the 'train' where the columns are both 1, `pull` the 'UNSCPSC' column and get the `length` of `unique` elements (`n_distinct`)

```
library(tidyverse)
pmap_int(associations, ~ train %>% 
                           filter(!! rlang::sym(.x) == 1, !! rlang::sym(.y) == 1) %>% 
                           pull(UNSPSC) %>% 
                           n_distinct)
#[1] 3 1 2
```